# Creating a JS form that outputs usable HTML

Tags: javascript, html, output

I'm working on creating a way for editors at my school's newspaper to be able to go to a page that would have places to type in info (ie. img url, titles, captions) and it would output HTML code that is already stylized.

So they type into the form in the title area: "Title"

And in the paragraph area: "This is a test"

and it would output something like this:

```
<div class="div1">
    <span>Title</span>
    <p>This is a test</p>
</div>
```

(div1 since since it's the first one you put and could add more later)

I've been looking into finding something like this, which I know it's possible, I just don't know where to start with this or what I would even google search. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**EDIT: We can't set up a Wordpress due to contracts with outside companies.**

Comment: Too broad... you can use anything from handmade code, templates, React.JS or even a CMS to achieve that. Client-side or server-side HTML generation. So many unspecified variables...

Comment: Set up wordpress probably.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and avoid trying to make an editor from scratch. Google `WYSIWYG editor` results will include CKEditor and TinyMCE, etc.  When you actually write JS well enough then you could make one from scratch and realize it's still not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to implement a solution yourself or use what is already out there.
This type of functionality is already built into platforms like Wordpress and SquareSpace out of the box via a WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) editor - similar to Stackoverflow's question box.

If you are looking to implement a custom solution then I would recommend looking into into markdown languages.
For example, here is one markdown javascript library called Remarkable:

https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable.

This code snippet is taken directly from their github README

```
var Remarkable = require('remarkable');
var md = new Remarkable();

console.log(md.render('# Remarkable rulezz!'));
// => <h1>Remarkable rulezz!</h1>
```

As you can see the markdown text is passed to a render function and it translates into html.

Alex